# Join query result with itself in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a query:

```
select product_id, price, price_day
from products
where price>10
```

and I want to join the result of this query with itself (if for example I want to get in the same row product's price and the price in **previous** day)

I can do this:

```
select * from 
(
select product_id, price, price_day
from products
where price>10
) as r1
join 
(
select product_id, price, price_day
from products
where price>10
) as r2
on r1.product_id=r2.product_id and r1.price_day=r2.price_day-1
```

but as you can see I am copying the original query, naming it a different name just to join its result with itself.

Another option is to create a temp table but then I have to remember to remove it.

Is there a more elegant way to join the result of a query with itself?

Comment: can you show us a part of products table? imho you do not need a join here

Comment: products table is simple: it holds product id, a price for a specific day and the serial number of that day.

Comment: then you can use pivot on dates......  check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428993/understanding-pivot-function-in-t-sql out....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

self join query will help

```
select a.product_ID,a.price
      ,a.price_day
      ,b.price as prevdayprice
      ,b.price_day as prevday 
from Table1 a 
inner join table1 b 
on a.product_ID=b.product_ID  and  a.price_day = b.price_day+1   
where a.price  >10
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a bunch of things, just a few options could be:

- Just let mysql handle the optimization

  - this will likely work fine until you hit  **many** rows
- Make a view for your base query and use that

  - could increase performance but mostly increases readability (if done right)
- Use a table (non temporary) and insert your initial rows in there.  [(unfortunately you cannot refer to a temporary table more than once in a query)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343402/getting-around-mysql-cant-reopen-table-error)

  - this will likely be more expensive performance wise until a certain number of rows is reached.

Depending on how important performance is for your situation and how many rows you need to work with the "best" choice would change.

Answer (score -1):

Just to get duplicates in the same row?

```
select product_id as id1, price as price1, price_day as priceday1, product_id as id2, price as price2, price_day as priceday2,
   from products
     where price>10
```

Comment: That's not what I asked. I want to get the price for the PREVIOUS day in the same row.

Comment: Your select statements are exactly the same: select product_id, price, price_day and are selecting from the same table

Comment: Look on my conditions of the join

Comment: So product_id is not unique? I don't understand your table.. where is this previous day value stored?

Comment: (product_id, price, price_day) is the primary key of the table