# Select corresponding non-aggregated column after group by statment in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a temporary table I've derived from a much larger table.

```
+-----+----------+---------+
| id  | phone    | attempt |
+-----+----------+---------+
|  1  | 12345678 |      15 |
|  2  | 87654321 |       0 |
|  4  | 12345678 |      16 |
|  5  | 12345678 |      14 |
|  10 | 87654321 |       1 |
|  11 | 87654321 |       2 |
+-----+----------+---------+
```

I need to find the id (unique) corresponding to the highest attempt made on each phone number. Phone and attempt are not unique.

```
SELECT id, MAX(attempt) FROM temp2 GROUP BY phone
```

The above query does not return the id for the corresponding max attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    t.*
from temp2 t
inner join (
    select phone, max(attempt) attempt
    from temp2
    group by phone
) t2 on t.phone = t2.phone
and t.attempt = t2.attempt;
```

It will return rows with max attempts for a given number.

Note that this will return multiple ids if there are multiple rows for a phone if the attempts are same as maximum attempts for that phone.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71953/5)

Comment: Says ERROR 1137 (HY000): Can't reopen table: 't'. I ran into this problem earlier as well. Turns out it's because this is temporary table

Comment: [You can't access the temp table more than once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343402/getting-around-mysql-cant-reopen-table-error). Don't use temp table, create view or a different table instead. The above and @Tim's solution is the way to solve this problem.

Comment: @Tim - Thanks for the fiddle :)

Comment: I went with creating another temporary table.

select
    t.*
from temp2 t
inner join (
    select msisdn, max(attempt) attempt
    from temp3
    group by phone
) t2 on t.phone = t2.phone
and t.attempt = t2.attempt;

Comment: @Prashan - Nice one. Was about to suggest that. :)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the answer given by @GurV, you could also solve this using a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM temp2 t1
WHERE t1.attempt = (SELECT MAX(t2.attempt) FROM temp2 t2 WHERE t2.phone = t1.phone)
```

This has the advantage of being a bit less verbose.  But I would probably go with the join option because it will scale better for large data sets.

### Demo