# Can the result of a subquery be joined with itself?

Tags: sql

Let's say I need to find the oldest animal in each zoo.  It's a typical maximum-of-a-group sort of query.  Only here's a complication: the zebras and giraffes are stored in separate tables.  To get a listing of all animals, be they giraffes or zebras, I can do this:

```
(SELECT id,zoo,age FROM zebras
 UNION ALL
 SELECT id,zoo,age FROM giraffes) t1
```

Then given `t1`, I could build a typical maximum-of-a-group query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
JOIN
(SELECT zoo,max(age) as max_age
 FROM t1
 GROUP BY zoo) t2
ON (t1.zoo = t2.zoo)
```

Clearly I could store `t1` as a temporary table, but is there a way I could do this all within one query, and without having to repeat the definition of `t1`?  (Please let's not discuss modifications to the table design; I want to focus on the issue of working with the subquery result.)

Comment: Your query is weird, it's the same as doing

SELECT t1.* FROM t1

since t2 will contain all possible zoos of t1, you join the zoo of t1 with t1 itself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to the with clause.

[Understanding the WITH Clause](http://gennick.com/with.html)

```
with t1 as
(select id, zoo, age from zebras
union all
select id, zoo, age from giraffes)
select t1.*
from t1
join
(SELECT zoo,max(age) as max_age
FROM t1
GROUP BY zoo) t2
on (t1.zoo = t2.zoo);
```

Note:  You could move t2 up to your with clause as well.

Note 2:  An alternative solution is to simply create t1 as a view and use it in your query instead.

Comment: i think this is not really sql standard compliant
edit: ups, yes it is :-) Was not aware of the 1999 one... sry!

Comment: I do think `WITH` is the way to go.  However it appears MySQL (the RDBMS I use most often) [may not support it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324935/mysql-with-clause)?  Frowny face if that is still true.

Answer (score 0):

To find the oldest animal, you should use wjndoq functions:

```
select z.*
from (select z.*,
           row_number() over (partition by zoo order by age desc) as seqnum
      from ( <subquery to union all animals>) z
     )
where seqnum = 1
```