# SQL WITH clause example

Tags: sql, with-clause

I was trying to understand how to use the `WITH` clause and the purpose of the `WITH` clause.

All I understood was, the `WITH` clause was a replacement for normal sub-queries.

Can anyone explain this to me with a small example in detail ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: are you using MYSQL? b/c it isn't supported.

Comment: I put together an example how to use the WITH clause to create temporary static table. You might find this useful, since it contains some examples on how to use WITH clauses in your queries.

http://www.giombetti.com/2014/02/14/using-sql-with-clause-to-create-temporary-static-tables-at-query-time/

Comment: since the OP made the post, MySQL implemented the WITH statement: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: Very inappropriate to mark as duplicate in my opinion, especially given that from an entry level, no-one would ever click on the question, and secondly the answer is wildly different. And this one is more practically useful...

Answer (score 351):

The SQL WITH clause was introduced by Oracle in the Oracle 9i release 2 database. The SQL WITH clause allows you to give a sub-query block a name (a process also called sub-query refactoring), which can be referenced in several places within the main SQL query. The name assigned to the sub-query is treated as though it was an inline view or table. The SQL WITH clause is basically a drop-in replacement to the normal sub-query.

Syntax For The SQL WITH Clause

The following is the syntax of the SQL WITH clause when using a single sub-query alias.

```
WITH <alias_name> AS (sql_subquery_statement)
SELECT column_list FROM <alias_name>[,table_name]
[WHERE <join_condition>]
```

When using multiple sub-query aliases, the syntax is as follows.

```
WITH <alias_name_A> AS (sql_subquery_statement),
<alias_name_B> AS(sql_subquery_statement_from_alias_name_A
or sql_subquery_statement )
SELECT <column_list>
FROM <alias_name_A>, <alias_name_B> [,table_names]
[WHERE <join_condition>]
```

In the syntax documentation above, the occurrences of `alias_name` is a meaningful name you would give to the sub-query after the AS clause. Each sub-query should be separated with a comma [Example for WITH statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/img_text/subquery_factoring_clause.htm). The rest of the queries follow the standard formats for simple and complex SQL SELECT queries.

For more information: http://www.brighthub.com/internet/web-development/articles/91893.aspx

Comment: :I've already seen it,can you explain this with a small example which would be more easy to under stand.

Comment: I think you need a comma after the WITH `<alias_name_A> AS (sql_subquery_statement)` when using multiple subquery aliases.

Comment: That is not really an example

Answer (score 118):

This has been fully answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324935/mysql-with-clause).

See [Oracle's docs on SELECT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2161315) to see how subquery factoring works, and Mark's example:

```
WITH employee AS (SELECT * FROM Employees)
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE ID < 20
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE Sex = 'M'
```

Comment: Thank you especially for the first sentence with a link :)

Comment: Yeah, basically it replaces a subquery BUT allows you to reference the "subquery" result in multiple places.

Comment: Shouldn't you mention the attributes in the in the parenthesis instead of (SELECT * FROM Employees)?  For example, WITH employee AS (Name, ID).

Comment: In MSSQL, you need to add a semicolon (;) before WITH, order wise you will get an error. it should be `;WITH blabla AS ...)`

Comment: @ObinnaNnenanya
In MSSQL, another approach is to have the WITH statement first, e.g. `WITH x as (...) SELECT ...`. Though you can/should put a semicolon after statements, and so put one before the word `SELECT`. But if you were trying to avoid semicolons, or looking for an approach that seems more readble, just put the WITH statement first.