# An equivalent expression for MIN_BY in SQL?

Tags: sql

In SQL we have the function `MIN_BY(B,C)`, which returns the value of `B` at the minimum of `C`.

How would one get the same functionality, but without using the `MIN_BY` function?

i.e. given columns `A,B,C`, I want to group by `A` and return the value of `B` that corresponds to the minimum of `C`. I can see there must be some way to do it using `OVER` and `PARTITION BY` but am not well versed in enough to see how!

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses window functions:

```
select a, min(min_bc)
from (select t.*, min(b) over (partition by a order by c) as min_bc
      from t
     )
group by a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to understand:

SETUP:

```
create table Test (a int, b int, c int);
insert into test values(1,2,3);
insert into test values(1,3,2);
insert into test values(1,4,1);
insert into test values(2,4,5);
insert into test values(2,8,4);
```

QUERY(min(b) for the case of multiple rows with minimum of c):

```
select a, min(b) from Test t
where c = (select min(c) from Test b where b.a = t.a)
group by a
```

RESULT:

```
A   MIN(B)
1   4
2   8
```

RESULT of Gordon Linoffs query:

```
A   MIN(MIN_BC)
1   2
2   4
```

Who's right, who's wrong and why

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use subquery or window functions, I wrote an alternative here (Works best for INT types as the comparator):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75289042/1997873