# Select a range of list from two string value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I recently encounter a problem in sql ,

I have a table called Plan which looks like as below order by Distance ...

```
 Distance Destination
 0         a
 1        null
 2        null
 3         b
 .        null
 .        null
 1050      c
```

I have two value as input from the user like a and b or b and c , how can I just get this range of value by using SQL

what I did is select the distance of a and b , and re-select all the list by doing distance > a.distance and distance < b.distance .
any idea of how to write this more efficient and more clever in one sql ? sorry for this noob question ;
my desire result is like when you input :b and c

return a list

```
 0         b
 .        null
 .        null
 1047      c
```

Comment: Like sample data can you also post expected data?

Comment: Show your desired results for the sample data,it`s not clear,at least for me.Sum of distance between 2 destinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `with` SQL statement

```
    WITH agreater AS (
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM 
            Plan 
        WHERE 
            distance >= (select distance from Plan where destination = 'a')
    )
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM 
        agreater
    WHERE 
        distance <= (select distance from agreater where destination = 'c')
```

---

You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12552325/4153426) to get some more info about `with`