# MySQL multiple column, single query

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-columns

I have a database, which hold data of customers. I need to know how many customers We have in individual city and country. I have to do it with single query.

My table is customers and I have columns city and country(both are varchar), which holds informations about it.

Desired output of query should look like this:

```
City | NumberOfCustomers | Country | NumberOfCustomers |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks

Comment: The desired output is weird. You're welcome

Comment: "I have to do it with single query" --- what technical reasons are behind this requirement?

Comment: @zerkms "Because my teacher told me so."

Comment: @Crontab: I bet it's not that, but something like "because 1 query is faster than 2" :-)

Comment: @zerkms You are probably right.  =)

Comment: @Crontab Because program will be build on it and requirement is to make it with single query. I am no pro in SQL, still learning.

Comment: @zerkms Can you tell me why is my desired output weird ? I just need to know how many customers are in individual city and in country. Sorry if its unclear. Didnt know how to make it more clear.

Comment: "Because 1 query is faster" --- it's not. For this task 1 query will be much more complicated and slower.

Comment: "Can you tell me why is my desired output weird ?" --- because you're mixing different entities in the same result set. "Sorry if its unclear." --- it is clear. And it is weird. You need to perform 2 queries: Number of customers per city; Number of customers per country

Comment: @zerkms I see. Is it even possible ? I made it with UNION but its quite messy as it creates only one column and put city and country data into it. I guess I used it in bad way.

Comment: @nifelvind: it is possible but it doesn't worth it. Just use 2 queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select city, country, count(*) from tbl group by 1,2 with rollup
```

Edit to show example table and output of that query:

```
mysql> select * from location;
+-------+---------+
| city  | country |
+-------+---------+
| City1 | US      |
| City2 | US      |
| City2 | US      |
| City3 | CA      |
| City3 | CA      |
| City3 | JP      |
+-------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select city, country, count(*) from location group by 1,2 with rollup;
+-------+---------+----------+
| city  | country | count(*) |
+-------+---------+----------+
| City1 | US      |        1 |
| City1 | NULL    |        1 |
| City2 | US      |        2 |
| City2 | NULL    |        2 |
| City3 | CA      |        2 |
| City3 | JP      |        1 |
| City3 | NULL    |        3 |
| NULL  | NULL    |        6 |
+-------+---------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Does MySQL support `with`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324935/mysql-with-clause

Comment: @showdev - I updated with an example to show how mysql's "with" is used

Comment: @atxdba Thanks. Is there any way to group them ? Like USA - 36 instead of having USA - 1 in 36 rows?

Comment: @atxdba Thanks for the edit, looks like I was confused.