# How to merge data from multiple columns into one? [Adjacency List Model Query]

Tags: mysql, sql

I've this query

```
SELECT t1.categoryid AS lev1, t2.categoryid as lev2, t3.categoryid as lev3, t4.categoryid as lev4
FROM category AS t1
LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.categoryid
LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.categoryid
LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.categoryid
WHERE t1.categoryid = 4149418031;
```

This is how to result looks like

[image]

As you can see it returns four columns. 
I want to merge distinct data of all four into one column.

I looked at similar questions but none of those has Left Joins in their query. 
 I know it can be possible using `union` but I'm struggling.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean distinct data? Distinct combination of categoryid 1,2,3,4? You could just nest your original query inside another query, where you select DISTINCT * from ( /*inner query*/).

Comment: @user3538411 There are four columns which could contain duplicate data. I want the distinct data from all the columns into one. I updated the question with query result. Have a look.

Comment: Hi Pranav. Were you able to solve this issue.I am also facing the same problem with converting the query from "with" to mysql version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you could use a `UNION` over the result of your query. In the rest of the answer I will show you a solution using CTE, which is a standard SQL syntax available in many systems, but, unfortunately, not in MySQL. However, to convert this query for MySQL you can look at the following answer: [How do you use the "WITH" clause in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql)

```
WITH query AS (
  SELECT t1.categoryid AS lev1, t2.categoryid as lev2, t3.categoryid as lev3, t4.categoryid as lev4
  FROM category AS t1
  LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.categoryid
  LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.categoryid
  LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.categoryid
  WHERE t1.categoryid = 4149418031)
SELECT lev1 AS category_value FROM query
  UNION
SELECT lev2 AS category_value FROM query
  UNION
SELECT lev3 AS category_value FROM query
  UNION
SELECT lev4 AS category_value FROM query;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!
Although I'm struggling to convert but I'll look into it.
Thanks, again.