# Excel : Get the most frequent value for each group

Tags: excel, ms-access, data-processing

I Have a table ( excel ) with two columns ( Time 'hh:mm:ss' , Value ) and i want to get most frequent value for each group of row.

for example i have

```
Time    | Value
4:35:49 | 122
4:35:49 | 122
4:35:50 | 121
4:35:50 | 121
4:35:50 | 111
4:35:51 | 122
4:35:51 | 111
4:35:51 | 111
4:35:51 | 132
4:35:51 | 132
```

And i want to get most frequent value of each Time

```
Time    | Value
4:35:49 | 122
4:35:50 | 121
4:35:51 | 132
```

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**
The first answer of @scott with helper column is the correct one

[See the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2WUa.png)

Comment: At 4:35:51, two rows have Value=111 and another two have Value=132.  So how do you determine 132 is "most frequent"?

Comment: If we find two or more values with same frequent we choose the highest value

Comment: You denote the correct answer by clicking the green check mark by the answer.  I have reverted it back to the original.

Comment: It's done ;) , I think i need to create a new separate question for SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a helper column:

First it will need a helper column so in C I put

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11,A2,$B$2:$B$11,B2)
```

Then in F2 I put the following Array Formula:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(MAX(IF($A$2:$A$11=E2,IF($C$2:$C$11 = MAX(IF($A$2:$A$11=E2,$C$2:$C$11)),$B$2:$B$11))),$B$2:$B$11,0))
```

It is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter. Then copied down.

I set it up like this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but doesn't just using `=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$11=E2,$B$2:$B$11))` give the same result?

Comment: @rwilson Not quite, but your comment made my think that I was over thinking, so I simplified.  the problem is that the OP wants when there is a tie that the higher value wins.

Comment: Excelent solution my brother, Thank you so much, Now am searching for the same solution with an sql query :D

Comment: Unfortunately @rwilson doesn't understand my question , I need to get the  most occurrent value of each time, your formula return the higher value of each time, it's not my goal :)

Comment: First answer of Scott seems ok

`=INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MATCH(MAX(IF($A$2:$A$11=E2,IF($C$2:$C$11 = MAX(IF($A$2:$A$11=E2,$C$2:$C$11)),$B$2:$B$11))),$B$2:$B$11,0))
`

Comment: @Horthe92 The shortened one step will do what you want.  It will return the highest if there are more than one that has the highest recurrence.  I just took the two formula and combined them to do it in one step.  The single formula should give the same answer as the two step.  rwilson's did spark me to shorten the formula and still get the same result.  If this is correct answer please mark it as such by clicking on the green check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this in MS Access:

```
select tv.*
from (select time, value, count(*) as cnt
      from t 
      group by time, value
     ) as tv
where exists (select 1
              from (select top 1 time, value, count(*) as cnt
                    from t as t2
                    where t.time = t2.time
                    group by time, value
                    order by count(*) desc, value desc
                  ) as x
              where x.time = tv.time and x.value = tv.value
             );
```

MS Access doesn't support features such as window functions or CTEs that make this type of query easier in other databases.

Comment: that would not work if two values are equally frequent at a given time right? Both would get selected

Comment: @Guig . . . I restructured the whole query so it will only return one value per time.

Answer (score 0):

Would that work? I haven't tried and got inspired [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

```
;WITH t3 AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY time ORDER BY c DESC, value DESC) AS rn
   FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS c, time, value FROM t GROUP BY time, value) AS t2
)
SELECT *
FROM t3
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Does it support mysql?

Comment: I hope so:) I can't test it a the moment

Comment: Ok, I'll try it , God bless you

Comment: It might not work with mysql.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324935/mysql-with-clause

Comment: The problem is not with "WITH" clause but with ROW_NUMBER(), "WITH" can be replaced with a sub-query i guess

Comment: Here is a way to get the row number: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select